# Matching pattern with regex: S(n,n+1)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following pattern
`sn,n+1`
where n is an integer. Examples include
`s1,2` `s3,4`

Right now I know how to match the following: `sn,n`
(for example `s1,1`) with regex. The syntax I use for this is `s(\d+),\1`

Is it possible to do something like the following? `s(\d+),\1+1`

More detail on my specific problem (these details aren't necessarily relevant to the solution! But I am including them anyway), I am using CST, an electromagnetic simulator that supports regex for sorting s-parameter data. With a high port count, it is cumbersome to manually select isolation between ports. So I want to use a regex in the above way.

Comment: Regular expressions can't do arithmetic.

Comment: @azro You are totally right, removing the comment.

Comment: Also note that has far as regexp is concerned, 1234 isn't even a number.  It's just a string of digits.  Regexp has no facility for convert strings of digits to numbers; it expects the programmer to do that outside the regexp code.

Comment: You can use the regex to extract the pairs of digits, then filter this output to check if it is n,n+1.. If the pattern is always something like `s1,2 s4,8 s9,4` don't use a regex, parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can not do arithmetic but python does. You can find all matching patterns in your string and filter them later with python. This might help:

**Regex**

```
import re
string= 's1,2 test s2,3 , test test s12,12'
pattern = 's\d+,\d+'
pattern_list = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(pattern_list)
['s1,2', 's2,3', 's12,12']
```

**Filtering with Python**

```
result_list = [i for i in pattern_list if int(i.split(',')[0].split('s')[1]) + 1  == int(i.split(',')[1]) ]
print(result_list)
['s1,2', 's2,3']
```

**Basically, it finds all patterns by using regex then python checks the patterns that fits to sn,n+1**

Comment: Got it, thanks. This is a good solution. I would have to make a macro to integrate in my electromagnetics simulator. A bit of an oversight on the developers part because this is a pretty typical use case for they regex integration.